# Dynamical overriding

Tags: c++, qt

[image]

I want to dynamically instantiate a `QWidget` and bind its "Pressed" event, either with a Qt signal or by overriding a function.

However I'm only allowed to create one new `.cpp` file.

I don't know how to override a C++ function dynamically, or how to change a virtual function into a Qt signal.

Is what is represented in the picture above achievable ?

Comment: why vote this question bad, is this question really bad?

Comment: Your question confuses many things. "Declaring dynamically" is not a thing. You don't override a function for a signal, nor do you override a function when doing declaration. Also, I don't see the connection to creating new cpp files. (Answer Question 1) You cannot override a function dynamically, nor can you change a virtual function into a signal. But you probably don't want to do either. Look at Qt's examples and go from there. Maybe read a C++ tutorial as well.

Comment: I've tried and cleared up your question with what I understood. Feel free to rollback or correct my edit if I didn't get it :)

Comment: Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Widgets Tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/widgets-tutorial.html) of the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/) is a nice starting point.
Under [Qt Widgets Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets.html) you can find the [Calculator Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-calculator-example.html), which should contain all of what you want to do.
Take the code, strip it down to what you need, use and try to understand it.

Or maybe have a look at the [Getting Started section](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html).

Comment: I know what you mean after read calculator example.
Thank you a lot.